# How to access and use matrices in prolog

Tags: matrix, prolog

I need random access to matrix locations in prolog (swipl). Suggest me a library that gives a way to create  and access random locations in matrix without having to go through the process of processing list.

Comment: Thanks that worked. But how can we change values in the array... For instance I want to change the value of A[3], then arg(3,A,4) didnt work as I want to change the value of A[3] to 4

Answer (score 3):

SWI-Prolog has unlimited arity terms, then you don't really need any external library. 
There are several builtins for access to term' arguments, I find [arg](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=arg/3) is handy. For instance:

```
?- A = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), arg(3, A, X).
X = 3.
```

Depending on what data you will need to process, and the frequency of access to these matrices, you could apply data hiding, providing yourself with the preferred interface.

For instance, you could need index validation:

```
?- A = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), arg(8, A, X).
false.
```

Note that no exception is thrown...

arg/3 can also *search* the matching argument:

```
?- A = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), arg(P, A, 4).
A = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
P = 4 .
```

**edit**

in Prolog, *assignment* must always be handled with care, because the programming *model* isn't really suited for that. But there are some builtins, like [nb_setarg](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=nb_setarg/3), that do the work. See the relevant documentation [section](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.20%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/manipterm.html%27%29%29).

Comment: Thanks that worked. But how can we change values in the array... For instance I want to change the value of A[3], then arg(3,A,4) didnt work as I want to change the value of A[3] to 4

Comment: -1: Using `nb_setarg` at a beginner level is definitely a very bad idea. First, the very ideas of Prolog should be understood. Also, `nb_setarg/3` is specific to SWI and YAP. It is absent or not present as a built-in in IF, B, GNU, SICStus, XSB, Ciao. Worse, even the semantics of `nb_setarg/3` is not well defined. So it is just a hack which will most probably change from release to release. And which has changed in the past already several times.

Comment: probably nb_setarg could be obsolete, given the recent advances in garbage collection in SWI-Prolog (that the OP required, albeit not tagged). I think that *especially* for beginners such 'hints' to more conventional programming tools is required.

Comment: @chac: I am unaware of GC advances in SWI that would influence this issue. The main point is that you cannot give it a semantics at all. Similar to the (global) ordering of variables which also remains implementation dependent ; i.e. practically undefined over "longer" periods. Where even defining "longer" is almost impossible... But it is worse here, as it affects also ground terms.